# When tagging a question, don't suggest tags that are already added

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta-tags

When tagging a question and a given tag is already added, it should be removed from the suggestion list. For example, if I have added all 6 tags that are initially suggested that start with a specific string, the tag suggestion should give me some new tags instead of those that I have just added.

[image]

Comment: You can only add 5 tags ;-).

Comment: Maybe, but that is not the point. The point is to improve user experience by reducing the few extra milliseconds that it takes me to realize that I have already added a given tag.

Comment: every millisecond counts nowadays..

Answer (score 2):

I often use this "feature" to read the tag description of a tag I already added.

Unfortunately, hovering over an already added tag doesn’t show the description.

I agree that already added tags shouldn’t be suggested, but then, please, allow checking the description of already added tags somehow (without having to remove them first).

EDIT: **It’s possible** by clicking at an already added tag. ([Thanks,  Dukeling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146805/when-tagging-a-question-dont-suggest-tags-that-are-already-added#comment751470_224980)!)

Comment: You can click on the tag to see its description.

Comment: @Dukeling: Oi, nice, I never noticed that. (Or is it new?). Thanks :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's been around for quite a while.