# Don't suggest tags that a question has already been tagged with

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-tags

> Related to [When tagging a question, don't suggest tags that are already added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146805/when-tagging-a-question-dont-suggest-tags-that-are-already-added), but that is on the auto-complete in the tag box.

When writing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183619/the-multicollider-is-translucent-on-some-sites-and-not-others) I got the following:

> [image]

I like that related tags are suggested to a user to tag but there's no point suggesting tags that have already been added, as I can't add them. The tag has been greyed out so the site knows I can't add it so why not just remove it altogether?

Comment: Cross-site post on MSO: [Editor suggests a tag I already used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405349/4642212).

Comment: I was just about to post this as a bug report on SO. Then I found out here that this has been a bug since 2013. Why is it rocket science to fix such a trivial bug?