# When can I / should I ask the same question, if there is no reaction to original one?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just ran through the issue [Don't suggest tags that a question has already been tagged with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183620/189165). The original question was asked 6+ years ago with no answer / reaction so far (it is a feature request, so it should be answered, right?).

Somebody asked [the very same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339764/189165) just a few days ago and that question was dupe-closed.

**If and when it is OK to ask the same question to encourage someone answering it?** I am aware of other ways to encourage answer to an existing question (upvote, bounty, comment, share etc.). But, I wanted to know, if generally asking the same question for reason of no reaction is OK?

Comment: "... if generally asking the same question for reason of no reaction is OK ..." Why should it? It would only increase the attention at the cost of duplicated content. Attention can be generated by bounties efficiently.

Comment: Sometimes you can get a bit more attention by making a well-timed edit to the question, but easy does it, overdoing this gets on people's nerves.  Also you can bring the question to the attention of some individual users that you think might not have seen it but who might be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If and when it is OK to ask the same question to encourage someone answering it?

Never.

The question may be outdated, e.g. using old screenshots which don't resemble the current UI anymore. That is a good reason to edit the question, which will bump it and draw a little more attention to it.

Unlike many other forums, Stack Exchange allows and even encourages answers to old questions; basically it doesn't really matter how old a question is, as long as it's a good one.

> it is a feature request, so it should be answered, right?

The lack of an answer (or a status tag like [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)) can (should?) be interpreted as 'this isn't high enough on our priority list right now'. Note: that might change in the future. There are simply too many bugs and feature requests and too few staff to respond to all of them.

---

<sub>You might think the downvotes on the question you linked to are an indication that the OP there gets punished for (deliberately?) posting a duplicate. I don't think that's the case, they simply didn't know about it. I don't understand why it's so heavily downvoted either.</sub>

Comment: Maybe also bounties could be added. They are typically used to attract additional attention. A feature-request should still be answered one way or another (even a "we don't think this is high priority"). No answer could simply be mistaken for "we missed that one". Even with few staff, posting a small preliminary response may be possible.